# C# - Converting multi page tiff file to base64 string and converting back results with single image

Tags: c#, base64, tiff

I'm opening a tiff file from local disk:

```
Image multiPageImage = Image.FromFile(fileName);
```

Then sending it to conversion method:

```
base64string = ImageToBase64(multiPageImage, ImageFormat.Tiff);

public static string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Convert Image to byte[]
                image.Save(ms, format);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

                // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }  
        }
```

Finally I convert my base64 to tiff file with the below code:

```
public static void ConvertBase64ToTiff(string base64string)
    {
        Byte[] bitmapData = new Byte[base64string.Length];

        bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(base64string));

        using (MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData))
        {
            Bitmap bitImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(streamBitmap));
            bitImage.Save(@"C:\myTiff.tiff");
        }            
    }

    public static string FixBase64ForImage(string base64string)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(base64string, base64string.Length);

        sbText.Replace("\r\n", String.Empty);
        sbText.Replace(" ", String.Empty);

        return sbText.ToString();
    }
```

That fixing method is not mine. Actually I don't know if it is the right way or not. But I searched everwhere and trying what I find.

My tests showed that base64 string has just a single image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For people who have a problem about converting multi page tiff file to base64 and vice versa you can refer to that link:

[Is it possible to create a base64 string which has all frames of a multi page tiff file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232385/is-it-possible-to-create-a-base64-string-which-has-all-frames-of-a-multi-page-ti)

Maybe it is not totally the same question but the answer will solve this one too.