# Is it possible to create a base64 string which has all frames of a multi page tiff file?

Tags: c#, .net, file, base64

Converting a multi page tiff file to base64 string by using known conversion methods seems to contain just a single page of it.

I'm getting the multi page tiff file from local disk:

```
Image multiPageImage = Image.FromFile(fileName);
```

Converting it to base64 string:

```
base64string = ImageToBase64(multiPageImage, ImageFormat.Tiff);

public static string ImageToBase64(Image image, ImageFormat format)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Convert Image to byte[]
        image.Save(ms, format);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

        image.Dispose();

        return base64String;
    }  
}
```

Then converting base64 to image back and saving it on the local disk to control the result:

```
public static Image ConvertBase64ToImage(string base64string)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);

    Image image;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);

        image.Save(@"C:\newTiff.tiff", ImageFormat.Tiff);
    }

    return image;
}
```

But result image has only single frame. That's why I'm asking if it is possible to have all frames in base64 string?

Comment: are you asking for a base64 string for each frame or the whole file?

Comment: Why not? You think about size limit or what?

Comment: is this what you need? `Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("image.tiff"))`?

Comment: @Dreamwalker Whole tiff file in a single base64 string.

Comment: Base64 has no limitation like _"Only contains the first page of a TIFF file"_ whatsoever. The problem must be in your code. Show your code.

Comment: or, at least define what you mean by `known conversion methods`

Comment: Ok I edited my code. Please have a look it.

Comment: The problem is not base64, it's your use of Image. See [How to open a multi-frame TIFF imageformat image in .NET 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401561/how-to-open-a-multi-frame-tiff-imageformat-image-in-net-2-0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing lot of unnecessary stuff just for reading a file and write it back to disk.

You can read all the content of file like this

```
var data = File.ReadAllBytes("image.tiff")
```

and then use `Convert.ToBase64String(data)` to convert it to a base 64 string.

```
var data = File.ReadAllBytes("image.tiff");
var result = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

then you can convert it back to it's byte representation and save it to disk.

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(result);
File.WriteAllBytes("image2.tiff", bytes);
```

[File.ReadAllBytes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Convert.ToBase64String()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The question _"How to base64-encode a file in C#"_ [has been answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475421/base64-encode-a-pdf-in-c). OP already is using code, which doesn't work. If they want help with that, they must show their code.